# Problem with Telerik RadGrid: ‘Telerik.Web.UI.GridInsertionObject’ does not contain a property with the name 'XXX '

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, radgrid

I've been trying to find the workaround for the following problem for the last couple of hours, but without any success. I've found many of the possible solutions on the Internet, but none of them was solution to my problem. I've also posted the same question on official Telerik's forum even though I'm almost sure that I'll get no response from them.

The problem occurs when I want to insert data into empty datasource. I've been able to find workarounds for RadComboBoxes, but not for the Textboxes. The error that is displayed is: "DataBinding: 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridInsertionObject' does not contain a property with the name 'OpciPrioritet'."

Here is the code:

**.ascx (needed for RadGrid):**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        Nadređeni ticket:
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbNadredeniTicket" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"
            Width="455px">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Prijavio:
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbPrijavio" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"
            Width="455px">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Asset:
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbAsset" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" Width="455px">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Opći prioritet:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOpciPrioritet" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.OpciPrioritet") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Tip:
    </td>
    <td>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbTip" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Status:
    </td>
    <td>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbStatus" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Datum prijave:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDatumPrijave" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DatumPrijave") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        Vrsta prijave:
    </td>
    <td>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbVrstaPrijave" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.VrstaPrijave") %>'
            runat="server">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Prioritet:
    </td>
    <td>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbPrioritet" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Prioritet") %>'
            runat="server">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        Deadline:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDeadline" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DatumDo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Opis:
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOpis" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="455px" Height="200px"
            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Opis") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Zatvoren ticket:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkZatvoren" runat="server" Checked='<%# CheckNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Zatvoren")) %>' />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Opis zatvorenog ticketa:
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOpisZatvorenog" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="455px"
            Height="200px" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.OpisZatvoren") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Bilješke:
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBiljeske" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="455px" Height="200px"
            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Biljeske") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text="Spremi" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Visible='<%# !(DataItem is Telerik.Web.UI.GridInsertionObject) %>'>
        </asp:Button>
        <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" Text="Spremi" runat="server" CommandName="PerformInsert"
            Visible='<%# DataItem is Telerik.Web.UI.GridInsertionObject %>'></asp:Button>

        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Odustani" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
            CommandName="Cancel"></asp:Button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**.aspx.cs (only the needed code snippet):**

```
        protected void gvTicketi_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        int idFirma = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["idt"]);

        if ((e.Item is GridEditFormItem) && e.Item.IsInEditMode )
        {
            GridEditFormItem editFormItem = (GridEditFormItem)e.Item;
            UserControl userControl = (UserControl)e.Item.FindControl(GridEditFormItem.EditFormUserControlID);

            TSEntities db = new TSEntities();
            Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
            TicketAsset ticketAsset = new TicketAsset();

            RadComboBox rcbTip = (RadComboBox)userControl.FindControl("rcbTip");
            rcbTip.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Incident"));
            rcbTip.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Reklamacija"));
            rcbTip.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Nova funkcionalnost"));
            rcbTip.DataBind();
            rcbTip.Text = "'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, 'DataItem.Tip') %>'";

            RadComboBox rcbStatus = (RadComboBox)userControl.FindControl("rcbStatus");
            rcbStatus.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("New"));
            rcbStatus.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("U radu"));
            rcbStatus.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("On hold"));
            rcbStatus.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Pending"));
            rcbStatus.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Scheduled"));
            rcbStatus.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Canceled"));
            rcbStatus.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Completed"));
            rcbStatus.DataBind();
            rcbStatus.Text = "'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, 'DataItem.Status') %>'";

            RadComboBox rcbVrstaPrijave = (RadComboBox)userControl.FindControl("rcbVrstaPrijave");
            rcbVrstaPrijave.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Usmeno"));
            rcbVrstaPrijave.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Telefon"));
            rcbVrstaPrijave.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("E-mail"));
            rcbVrstaPrijave.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Web"));
            rcbVrstaPrijave.DataBind();
            rcbVrstaPrijave.Text = "'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, 'DataItem.VrstaPrijave') %>'";

            RadComboBox rcbPrioritet = (RadComboBox)userControl.FindControl("rcbPrioritet");
            rcbPrioritet.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Low"));
            rcbPrioritet.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Normal"));
            rcbPrioritet.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("High"));
            rcbPrioritet.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Odmah"));
            rcbPrioritet.DataBind();
            rcbPrioritet.Text = "'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, 'DataItem.Prioritet') %>'";

            RadComboBox rcbNadredeniTicket = (RadComboBox)userControl.FindControl("rcbNadredeniTicket");
            var nadredenTicketList = (from t in db.Ticket
                                        select t).ToList();

            if (nadredenTicketList.Count > 0)
            {
                rcbNadredeniTicket.DataSource = from t in nadredenTicketList
                                                where t.idFirma == idFirma && t.Zatvoren == false
                                                select new { t.idTicket, t.idNadredeniTicket, OpisTicketa = t.idTicket + " - " + t.Opis };

                rcbNadredeniTicket.DataTextField = "OpisTicketa";
                rcbNadredeniTicket.DataValueField = "idTicket";
                rcbNadredeniTicket.Text = "'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, 'DataItem.idNadredeniTicket') %>'";
            }

            rcbNadredeniTicket.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Bez nadređenog ticketa", "0"));
            rcbNadredeniTicket.DataBind();

            RadComboBox rcbPrijavio = (RadComboBox)userControl.FindControl("rcbPrijavio");
            rcbPrijavio.DataSource = from k in db.Kontakt
                                     where k.idFirma == idFirma
                                     select new { k.idKontakt, kontaktNaziv = k.Ime + " " + k.Prezime };

            rcbPrijavio.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Bez kontakta", "0"));
            rcbPrijavio.DataTextField = "kontaktNaziv";
            rcbPrijavio.DataValueField = "idKontakt";
            rcbPrijavio.Text = "'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, 'DataItem.idKontakt') %>'";
            rcbPrijavio.DataBind();

            RadComboBox rcbAsset = (RadComboBox)userControl.FindControl("rcbAsset");
            var assetList = (from a in db.Asset
                             where a.idFirma == idFirma
                             select a).ToList();

            if (assetList.Count > 0)
            {
                var assets = from a in assetList
                             where a.idFirma == idFirma
                             select new { a.idAsset, Naziv = a.Naziv + " (" + a.Kontakt.Ime + " " + a.Kontakt.Prezime + ")" };

                rcbAsset.DataSource = assets;
                rcbAsset.DataTextField = "Naziv";
                rcbAsset.DataValueField = "idAsset";
                rcbAsset.Text = "'<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, 'DataItem.Naziv') %>'";
                rcbAsset.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem("Bez pridruženog asseta", "0"));
                rcbAsset.DataBind();
            }                             


            if (!e.Item.OwnerTableView.IsItemInserted)
            {
                int idTicket = Convert.ToInt32(editFormItem.GetDataKeyValue("idTicket"));
                ticket = db.Ticket.SingleOrDefault(t => t.idTicket == idTicket);

                string tip = ticket.Tip;
                rcbTip.Items.FindItemByText(tip).Selected = true;

                string status = ticket.Status;
                rcbStatus.Items.FindItemByText(status).Selected = true;

                string vrstaPrijave = ticket.VrstaPrijave;
                rcbVrstaPrijave.Items.FindItemByText(vrstaPrijave).Selected = true;

                string prioritet = ticket.Prioritet;
                rcbPrioritet.Items.FindItemByText(prioritet).Selected = true;

                int kontakt = Convert.ToInt32(ticket.idKontakt);

                if (ticket.idKontakt == null)
                {
                    rcbPrijavio.Items.FindItemByValue("0").Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    rcbPrijavio.Items.FindItemByValue(kontakt.ToString()).Selected = true;
                }

                int nadredeniTicket = Convert.ToInt32(ticket.idNadredeniTicket);

                if (ticket.idNadredeniTicket == null)
                {
                    rcbNadredeniTicket.Items.FindItemByValue("0").Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    rcbNadredeniTicket.Items.FindItemByValue(nadredeniTicket.ToString()).Selected = true;
                }

                var ticketAssetCount = from ta in db.TicketAsset
                                       where ta.idTicket == idTicket
                                       select ta;                  

                if (ticketAssetCount.Count() > 0)
                {
                    ticketAsset = db.TicketAsset.SingleOrDefault(ta => ta.idTicket == idTicket);

                    int asset = Convert.ToInt32(ticketAsset.idAsset);

                    rcbAsset.Items.FindItemByValue(asset.ToString()).Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    rcbAsset.Items.FindItemByValue("0").Selected = true;
                }
            }
            else if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.IsItemInserted)
            {
                var newVals = new System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary();
                newVals["OpciPrioritet"] = string.Empty;
                e.Item.OwnerTableView.InsertItem(newVals);
            }
        }
    }
```

**.aspx:**

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="gvTicketi" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" 
    onneeddatasource="gvTicketi_NeedDataSource" 
    onitemdatabound="gvTicketi_ItemDataBound" 
    oninsertcommand="gvTicketi_InsertCommand" 
    onupdatecommand="gvTicketi_UpdateCommand">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="idTicket" CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom" InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage">
        <CommandItemSettings AddNewRecordText="Dodaj novi ticket" RefreshText="Prikaži sve tickete" />
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="idTicket" HeaderText="Ticket" DataField="idTicket">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="idKontakt" HeaderText="Kontakt" DataField="idKontakt">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="idManager" HeaderText="Manager" DataField="idManager">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Opis" HeaderText="Opis" DataField="Opis">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="TicketNumber" HeaderText="Broj ticketa" DataField="TicketNumber">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="DatumPrijave" HeaderText="Datum prijave" DataField="DatumPrijave" DataFormatString="{0:dd.MM.yyyy.}">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="VrstaPrijave" HeaderText="Vrsta prijave" DataField="VrstaPrijave">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Tip" HeaderText="Tip" DataField="Tip">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Status" HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Prioritet" HeaderText="Prioritet" DataField="Prioritet">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="OpciPrioritet" HeaderText="Opći prioritet" DataField="OpciPrioritet">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Deadline" HeaderText="Deadline" DataField="DatumDo" DataFormatString="{0:dd.MM.yyyy.}">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn UniqueName="Zatvoren" HeaderText="Zatvoren" DataField="Zatvoren">
            </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
            <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn">
            </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
            <telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="DeleteColumn" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"
                ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" ConfirmText="Brisanje ticketa!" />
        </Columns>
        <EditFormSettings UserControlName="UserControls/TicketUserControl.ascx" EditFormType="WebUserControl">
            <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1">
            </EditColumn>
        </EditFormSettings>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

I really hope you guys will be able to help me so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I was able to find a workaround. What you have to do is to add ItemCommand event.

```
protected void gvTicketi_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName)
        {
            e.Canceled = true;
            System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary newValues = new System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary();
            newValues["DatumPrijave"] = " ";
            newValues["DatumDo"] = " ";
            newValues["Opis"] = " ";
            newValues["OpisZatvoren"] = " ";
            newValues["Biljeske"] = " ";
            newValues["Zatvoren"] = false;
            newValues["Asset"] = "Bez pridruženog asseta";

            e.Item.OwnerTableView.InsertItem(newValues);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding one of the following to the databinding of the RadTextBox:

First attempt:

```
Text='<%# Eval("DataItem.OpciPrioritet") ?? String.Empty %>'
```

Second attempt:

```
Text='<%# Eval("DataItem.OpciPrioritet") != null ? Eval("DataItem.OpciPrioritet") : String.Empty %>'
```

Third attempt:

```
Text='<%# Eval("DataItem.OpciPrioritet") != DBNull.Value ? Eval("DataItem.OpciPrioritet") : String.Empty %>'
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but, unfortunately none of the variations did work. I was able to find out something by myself. Actually, I'd be glad if your answer had worked for me because it is more elegant, but unfortunately it hadn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with `GridDropDownColumn`s inside of RadGrids when the field in the object connected to the `GridDropDownColumn` is not nullable. The `DefaultInsertValue` property was the key for me. I set it to 0 for a dropdown with integers in the `DataField`.

```
<telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataField="SomeDataID" HeaderText="SomeData" 
    DataSourceID="SomeDataSource" ListValueField="ID" ListTextField="Name" 
    DefaultInsertValue="0">
</telerik:GridDropDownColumn>
```

If your data type is not nullable like mine, I would add validation using the `ColumnValidationSettings` tag in the column to make sure it is filled in or you will likely get an error on submission.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your gvTicketi_NeedDataSource handler wires your grid up to a `List<T>` not `IEnumerable<T>`. Solved the issue for me.

Source: http://dotfresh.blogspot.com/2010/01/fixing-telerikwebuigridinsertionobject.html